# put 3 different values from database to Hashmaps

Tags: java, database, date, hashmap

In my database, I have 3 columns: `Date(PrimaryKey, TEXT)`, `FlightNumber(PrimaryKey, INTEGER)`, and `LoadEstimate(INTEGER)`. What I would like to do is put all the values from database into a hashmap. I have to make sure that all the datatypes are correct in order to load them into it and would like to filter the `LoadEstimate` data by user input (a  date and the flight number) and then return the predicted number for `LoadEstimate` and if none return `-1`.

Here is my database:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Text

Combine your date and flight number together as a String. Perhaps include a delimiter between them for easier reading by humans and parsing by machine.

That combined text is your key for the map. The integer number of load factor is your value for the map.

```
Map< String , Integer > map = new HashMap<>() ;
```

Use [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) to access the database. Loop your incoming database data. For each database row, combine the two fields, and enter into the map with the third field.

```
String k = localDate.toString() + "F" + flightNumber ;
Integer v = loadFactor ;
map.put( k , v ) ;
```

Retrieve. The `getOrDefault` method returns a default value if the map does not find a value. You said you want a -1 as default.

```
Integer loadFactor = map.getOrDefault( k , Integer.valueOf( -1 ) ;
```

## Object

Alternatively, you could create a class to hold the date and flight number.

The new records feature in Java 16 is ideal for that. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. Note that you can define your record locally, within the code block where you use it.

For older Java, write a conventional class instead of a record.

```java
record DateFlight ( LocalDate localDate , Integer flightNumber ) {}
```

Define your map as:

```
Map< DateFlight , Integer > map = new HashMap<>() ;
```

And call `put`:

```java
DateFlight k = new DateFlight( localDate , flightNumber ) ;
Integer v = loadFactor ;
map.put( k , v ) ;
```

## Choosing a `Map`

You have a variety of `Map` implementations to choose from, bundled with Java. Third parties provide implementations as well.

I would probably start with a `HashMap` to load data. Then make from that a non-modifiable map of unspecified class using `Map.copyOf` in Java 9 and later.

```java
Map< DateFlight , Integer > dataLoad = new HashMap<>() ; 
… load data
Map< DateFlight , Integer > map = Map.copyOf( dataLoad ) ; // Make unmodifiable `Map`.
```

Here is a graphic I made as a guide to the bundled maps.

[image]

Comment: Thank You! i have put all my values into the hashmaps for now, but i m just dont know how to fitter the values to get LoadEstiamted

Comment: @JiayaoWang You are not filtering, which means you expect multiple results. You expect one specific load estimate number for one specific date-with-flight-number. You are asking the map to retrieve exactly one value attached to one specific key. You ask the map by calling the `getOrDefault` method as shown in my Answer. That is the main purpose of a `Map`: You ask for a value assigned to a key.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution that doesn't force you to create a new kind of Object to store a row's info is this one:

A Hashmap contains key-value pairs and maps each unique key to a value.

According to the SQL database info you have provided your table has a composite primary key, in other words your primary key consists of two columns (a date of type TEXT and a flightNumber of type INTEGER).

As you know a primary key has unique values in order to help you make distinctions when querying data in a table. So, you should store in your hashmap as a key the primary key of your table.

Now, since your primary key consists of two columns and it's the combination of their values that helps you identify uniqueness, you can create an array or a list and store there the date and the * flightNumber*. Then, you will add to your hashmap this array/list as a key and the rest of the fields you want (in our case the loadEstimate of type INTEGER) as its value.

The above in code should be something like this:

```
HashMap<ArrayList<Object>, int> myMap = new HashMap<>(); //Create your hashmap

while (rs.next()) {
    LocalDate  date = LocalDate.parse(rs.getString("Date"));
    int  flightnumber = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("FlightNumber"));
    int loadestimate = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("LoadEstimate"));

    //Create array resembling the primary key
    ArrayList<Object> mapKey = new ArrayList<>();
    mapKey.add(date);
    mapKey.add(new Integer(flightnumber));

   //Store to Map the key and the value
   myMap.put(mapKey, loadestimate);
}
//then do sth with the hashmap
```

Notice that I create an array of generic objects of type Object in order to be able to store objects of different kind. This is possible, since they both subclasses of the class Object.